# Cross correlation theorem for single-sided Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution, correlation

I'm trying to prove the cross correlation theorem for the single-sided Laplace transform.  Define the cross correlation for two functions $f, g: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{C}^n$ to be
$$
(f\star g)(t) = \int_0^\infty f(\tau)^* g(t + \tau)d\tau.
$$
The cross correlation theorem (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)) then states that the single-sided Laplace transform of $f\star g$ is given by
$$
F^*(-s^*)\cdot G(s).
$$

*Proof attempt*

$$
\mathcal{L}(f\star g)(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st} \int_0^\infty f(\tau)^*g(t + \tau)d\tau dt\\
= \int_0^\infty f(\tau)^* \int_0^\infty e^{-st} g(t + \tau) dt d\tau.
$$
Set $u = t + \tau$ and evaluate the inner integral:

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-st} g(t + \tau) dt = \int_0^\infty e^{-s(u - \tau)} g(u)du\\
= e^{s\tau} \int_0^\infty e^{-su} g(u) du\\
= e^{s\tau} G(s).
$$
We are then left with
$$
\int_0^\infty f(\tau)^* e^{s\tau} d\tau G(s).
$$
If we were using the two-sided Laplace transform, the result would then follow by substituting $\omega = - \tau$.  In the single-sided setting, however, this doesn't work, as $f$ only takes positive arguments.

I suppose one way around this issue is to extend $f$ and $g$ to $(-\infty, \infty)$, setting them to $0$ on $(-\infty, 0]$.  The result can then be derived using the two-sided Laplace transform, which is equal to the single-sided Laplace transform in this case.  It is a bit unsatisfying though, a direct proof would be nice.

Thanks in advance for pointing out where I'm being stupid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This theorem does not appear to be true in general. A counterexample:

Take $g(t)=\exp(-ta)$ with $a$ such that $F^*(a^*)$ exists.
Then
\begin{align}
(f\star g)(t) &= \exp(-ta) \int_0^\infty f(\tau)^* \exp(-\tau a) d\tau \\&= \exp(-ta) \mathcal{L}\{f^*\}(a) \\&= g(t) F^*(a^*).
\end{align}
So the Laplace transform is
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{f\star g\}(s) &= F^*(a^*) \mathcal{L}\{g(t)\}(s) \\&= F^*(a^*) G(s).
\end{align}
But the theorem states that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{f\star g\}(s) = F^*(-s^*) G(s).
\end{align}
Since $F^*(a^*) = F^*(-s^*)$ is not true in general, the theorem is also not true in general.

In your proof, you forgot to update the limits of the integral after setting $u=t+\tau$:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \exp(-st) g(t+\tau) dt = \int_\tau^\infty \exp(-s(u-\tau)) g(u) du \neq \int_0^\infty \exp(-s(u-\tau)) g(u) du.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make $\tau$ negative but what if we play around with $s$? $$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty}f^*(\tau)e^{s\tau}d\tau&=\int_{0}^{\infty}f^*(\tau)e^{-(-s)\tau}d\tau\\\\&=\mathcal{ULT}\{f^*(t)\}_{s=-s}\\\\&=\mathcal{F}^*(s^*)_{s=-s}\\\\&=\mathcal{F^*}(-s^*)\end{align}$$

(As, $(-s)^*=-s^*$)

Comment: Of course!  Thanks.  So obvious once you see it!